# JMeter not able to open test plan ConversionException

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter almost every day.

Today when I try open my test plan (.jmx file), I get error (screenshot below).

Yesterday it worked with no problem and I did not install anything new,  new plugin or new version of JMeter.

I found similar issues here, so I tried to install jmeter-plugins-manager-1.1.jar then update other plugins but no changes, still same error.

I tried newest version of JMeter 4.0 but it didn't help neither.

error from version 3.1 (yesterday works)
[image]

error from version 4.0
[image]

Comment: Open your JMX file in notepad or  notepad++go to line no 7148 and see what its doing ..
You  may get an idea of what is causing this issue..

Comment: Thanks, something must damaged my file becouse line in error message is last line and file didnt ends properly as XML file.

Comment: Luckily jMeter doing backups of .jmx Test Plans so i found older version of my correct project. INSTALLATION_FOLDER/backups

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is about [CorrectedResultCollector](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/infra/common/src/main/java/kg/apc/jmeter/vizualizers/CorrectedResultCollector.java) so my expectation is that your Test Plan contains some [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)

1. Download [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) and drop it to `lib/ext` folder of your JMeter installation
2. Restart JMeter to pick it up
3. Open your test - the Plugin Manager should suggest you to install dependencies.

The class itself lives in [jmeter-plugins-common](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-common/1.4.0) jar however there could be more plugins which are missing in your current JMeter setup.

Comment: I tried this according to similar issues, but it didnt help